# An expression about "v-ing" verbs

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

Do you use adverbs to modify these v-ing words especially when they are the objects of the verbs?

Example:

> I regret swimming hurriedly
>   **I regret hurried swimming.

And what about these two sentences:

> I regret stamp-collecting
>   I regret collecting stamps
>
> I regret unnecessary bomb-defusing.
>   I regret bomb-defusing unnecessarily?

Besides, when using these words, it still retains the verbal characteristics right? Like:

> The house needs a careful cleaning

has the same meaning as:

> The house needs carefully cleaning
>   The house needs to be cleaned carefully (SOMETHING like passive voice)

Comment: In [this extract from a work by Quirk et al](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ApwSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=Quirk+gradience+painting&source=bl&ots=ERzHdWj2Gd&sig=U7xcXmffzxuGgQnlyvtueo7ovY0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmtdqsyJ7OAhVmGsAKHRh0CkkQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=Quirk%20gradience%20painting&f=false), (some of) the many different ways in which ing-forms are used in English are listed. Note that both 'Brown's deft painting of his daughter is a delight to watch' and 'Brown's deftly painting his daughter is a delight to watch' are grammatical (if very formal, at least for the second sentence).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Somebody has told me the first one is seldom used. Besides, could you please help me check if my cases are right or not?